# Desplegar opciones en ciertas zonas solo si está autenticado. React JS

Tags: reactjs, redux

Tengo un proyecto con React JS que estoy trabajando con Redux. Sé que para rutas que sean exclusivamente privadas puedo crear un "PrivateRoute" y verificar si está autenticado.

Pero, ¿cómo puedo desplegar opciones específicas como: "Me gusta", "Comentar" en un componente solo si el usuario está autenticado? Esto ya que esa ruta también puede ser accesible sin necesidad de hacer inicio de sesión.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En mi experiencia esto se suele hacer comprobando algún dato local, normalmente cuando estas logueado, guardas un token localmente, en localStorage, en un redux persistente, etc.

Entonces puedes hacer un componente que compruebe que exista un valor en ese parametro y si tiene valor, mostrar su hijo, sino no mostrar nada, algo así:

```
const PrivateComponent = ({children}) =>{

    const[authenticated,setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() =>{
        setAuthenticated(localStorage.getItem("token") ? true : false);
    },[])

    return authenticated && <>{children}</>
}
```

Y luego hacer esto:

```
<PrivateComponent><MiComponentePrivado /></PrivateComponent>
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que no se esta comprobando que ese token sea válido o no, solo estas comprobando si tiene token o no, lo importante es validar ese token en las acciones que se hacen en el back.